# Opening a URL in a WPF app with Frame opens it inside th

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have a WPF app on .NET Core 3.1. I want to open a URL in a default browser, this is the code I use

```
var ps = new ProcessStartInfo(url)
{
    UseShellExecute = true,
    Verb = "open"
};
Process.Start(ps);
```

This works fine until I put a `Frame` on the Window - when I do that instead of going to the  default browser, the URL is open inside the Frame (`Navigating` and `Navigated` events get triggerd).

How do I prevent that? I always want to open the default (external) browser). Here's the Frame:

```
<Frame 
    x:Name="Frame"
    MaxWidth="400"
    NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
    JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
    Navigating="FrameNavigating"
    IsTabStop="False"
    Focusable="False"
    />
```

Note that I set `JournalOwnership` to `OwnsJournal` because this frame is actually inside another (outter) frame. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Does Process.Start("default", ps) resolve your issue?  By the way. I would advise considering viewmodel first and usercontrols in a contentcontrol rather than frames and pages.

Comment: You can simply prevent into `Navigating` event by `e.Cancel = true;` and start the new process to open browser `Process.Start(Convert.ToString(e.Uri));`

Comment: @Andy it throws exception `Win32Exception (1155): No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.`
@DarshanFaldu That throws an exception `Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified`